# Screen Resolution and ATI HD6850 Drivers Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, resolution, screen

I am running dual monitors with an Sapphire HD6850 graphics card. My main monitor a 22" flat screen plugged in with a DVI port gets full 1680 x 1080 resolution. My second monitor is stuck at 1024 x 768 and is fairly blurry when in windows it can be up to 1280 x 960. How can I increase screen resolution and fix the blurriness. Im running ubuntu 12.10

I never figured out how to install the ATI Catalyst control ether. When I did put in ATI proprietary drivers the menu bar would not appear.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst Control Centre (CCC) should come installed with the drivers. If not, you should follow these instructions to reinstall the drivers/CCC and set them up correctly:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)